# bios won't load on laptop (110-15acl)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios

On my laptop (lenovo 110-15acl) there is a special button next to the stub that allows you to boot into the BIOS, boot manager, etc.  I always used it to boot into BIOS, however this time I also clicked on it, I got the novo button menu window, I choose BIOS setup, but the laptop booted into Windows, I repeated many times, but to no avail.  Thanks in advance for your advice.

things that didn't work

1. BIOS updating
2. using <kbd>F2</kbd> to boot into BIOS
3. using system recovery to boot into BIOS
4. turning off fast boot

Answer (score 0):

There is another method.  First.. let it boot into windows.

1. Search for “Settings” in the Start menu and open it.
2. Go to “Update and Security -> Recovery,” and click on the “Restart Now” button under the Advanced Start-up section.
3. In the dialog that appears.. click Troubleshoot.
4. Click Advanced options.
5. Select UEFI Firmware Settings.

Technically, most computers don't have BIOS anymore.  They have UEFI.

Comment: i tried it, but it load into windows

Comment: yes, I do everything according to your instructions, but when I click the uefi software settings, the laptop just reboots into the windows system.  only boot manager works for me

Comment: sorry. I did my best.  Good luck.

Comment: thank you for help!